# How to get focus back for parent window from an iframe programmatically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, focus

Some websites have `focus` set on an element on window load. If I iframe that website, It seems not able to set focus on parent window, programmatically. This only happens to `IE` (9) and `Firefox` (19), Opera/Safari/Chrome are fine.

```javascript
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // this does not focus #foo
        document.getElementById("foo").focus();
    // or more seconds that enough to see the iframe focus
    }, 3000);
};
</script>
<input id="foo" type="text" value="foo" /><br />
<iframe width="800" height="500" src="http://www.bing.com" />
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Isnt "alert" a modal window?

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin this question has nothing to do with alert. removed from example.

Comment: oh i miss-understood the question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got the answer, now it works on all browsers

```javascript
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    // blur the iframe
    document.getElementById("bing").blur();
    // set focus on #foo
    document.getElementById("foo").focus();
    // when iframe tries to focus, focus #foo
    document.getElementById("foo").onblur = function() {
        this.focus();
    };
};
</script>
<input id="foo" type="text" value="foo" /><br />
<iframe id="bing" width="800" height="500" src="http://wwww.bing.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've read this correctly you just need to prevent the focus being shifted from the parent window to an element in the iframe.

I would use an 'onfocus' trigger on the iframe element to switch the focus back to your page, like so:

```
<iframe width="800" height="500" src="http://www.bing.com" onfocus="document.getElementById('foo').focus();"/>
```

If (as I suspect you do) you only want to prevent the iframe stealing the initial focus onload but would like the user to be able to shift focus to it later, use a status variable, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var initialFocus = false;
</script>

<iframe width="800" height="500" src="http://www.bing.com" onfocus="if (initialFocus==false) { document.getElementById('foo').focus(); initialFocus = true; }"/>
```

I hope this helps and I'm here if you have any questions.

Comment: Both methods seem to work only on IE. Firefox still can't gain focus on parent window.

Comment: @user1643156 Is this page online, so I can have a look at it? If not, I can setup a test myself - just quicker if you've already go it up.

Comment: I'm testing this with bing.com like in the example. Just make sure you use Firefox and IE.

Comment: @user1643156 Cool. Just a quick question through... the onblur function for the element foo, won't it prevent the user ever changing the focus from the input element to something else? It seems very limiting.

Comment: @user1643156 Oh, and the reason what I posted didn't work in firefox is that FF is very peculiar about adding onfocus events to iframes. There are workarounds though, so just google it and you'll be able to modify the code accordingly.   Anyway, I'm glad you've got a solution.

Comment: `It seems very limiting` yes, but for my specific project, it's ok, there's nothing else but an iframe on the page. all the actions are being done with mouse and keyboard actions. maybe I could unbind the `onblur` once parent window gets focused.