# Click on content inside iframe kills fancyBox keyboard navigation (prev/next via Arrow keys)

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox-2

I've a peculiar issue with fancyBox.

First of all: [here is my demo of the issue](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=558D3A55BFED4CC5!6906&authkey=!AMYNF6GKqA_k078&ithint=file%2czip).

The problem is this: I've a page with multiple link. Each link opens a fancyBox iframe URL with some content in it.

Example of the "main" page:

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="content1.html">link1</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="content2.html">link2</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="content4.html">link3</a>


<script>
        var fancyboxOptions = {
                    autoSize    : false,
                    fitToView   : true,
                    width       : '50%',
                    height      : '50%',
        };

        $(".fancybox").fancybox(fancyboxOptions);
</script>
```

Example of the iframe-opened page:

```
<p>
    Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text
</p>
```

If you just open a link everything works fine: you can use the keyboard's Arrow keys left and right to go to the next and previous link.

The issue arises when you click anything inside the fancyBox-opened window: the click disrupts the ability to use the keyboard to go next/prev.

Switching to fancybox.ajax effectively solves the problem, but the whole page is pretty complex and many part are already coded with the iframe-based approach in mind, so switching fancyBox method is not an option.

[I already reported this as a fancyBox bug](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/1118), but I'm also looking for ideas to implement a quick fix on my side.

Thanks!

Comment: If you click something in the iframe, doesn't it put the focus into the iframe so it is expected behaviour? Let me give you an example - if something in the iframe had a keydown event bound to the arrow keys and you pressed them whilst the focus was in the iframe, you wouldn't then want the parent to navigate away from that iframe - you would want the iframe page event to work

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792620/how-to-get-focus-back-for-parent-window-from-an-iframe-programmatically-in-javas